# Create conditions for coupon rule in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, catalog-price-rules, coupon

I'm trying to create conditions in the coupon rules, but when creating the conditions they are not aggregated correctly

Im doing:

```
        $rule = $this->couponRule;

        $cond['conditions']['1']['type']= 'Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Combine';
        $cond['conditions']['1']['new_child']= '';
        $cond['conditions']['1']['aggregator']= 'all';
        $cond['conditions']['1']['value']= 1;
        $cond['conditions']['1--1']['type']= 'Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product\Found';
        $cond['conditions']['1--1']['new_child']= '';
        $cond['conditions']['1--1']['value']= 1;
        $cond['conditions']['1--1']['aggregator']= 'all';
        $cond['conditions']['1--1--1']['type']= 'Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product';
        $cond['conditions']['1--1--1']['attribute']= 'category_ids';
        $cond['conditions']['1--1--1']['attribute_scope']= 'parent';
        $cond['conditions']['1--1--1']['operator']= '!{}';
        $cond['conditions']['1--1--1']['value']= 10;

        try {
            $rule->setName('Cupom Dinâmico')
                ->setDescription('Criado dinamicamente')
                ->setUsesPerCustomer(1)
                ->setUsesPerCoupon(1)
                ->setIsActive(1)
                ->setSimpleAction('by_percent')
                ->setDiscountAmount($discount_amount)
                ->setDiscountQty(1)
                ->setApplyToShipping('no')
                ->setTimesUsed(1)
                ->setCouponType(2)
                ->setCustomerGroupIds('0,1,2,3')
                ->setWebsiteIds('1,2,4')
                ->setConditionsSerialized($this->serializer->serialize($cond))
                ->setCouponCode($coupon_code);


            $rule->save();
            return [
                'error' => false,
                'coupon_code' => $coupon_code,
                'discount_amount' => $discount_amount
            ];

        } catch (\Exception $e){
            return false;
        }
```

As the rule is being displayed:

[image]

How it should be:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was actually making a mistake in assembling the vector. The correct is:

```
$cond = array (
            'type' => 'Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Combine',
            'attribute' => NULL,
            'operator' => NULL,
            'value' => '1',
            'is_value_processed' => NULL,
            'aggregator' => 'all',
            'conditions' =>
                array (
                    0 =>
                        array (
                            'type' => 'Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Product\\Found',
                            'attribute' => NULL,
                            'operator' => NULL,
                            'value' => '1',
                            'is_value_processed' => NULL,
                            'aggregator' => 'all',
                            'conditions' =>
                                array (
                                    0 =>
                                        array (
                                            'type' => 'Magento\\SalesRule\\Model\\Rule\\Condition\\Product',
                                            'attribute' => 'category_ids',
                                            'operator' => '!{}',
                                            'value' => '10',
                                            'is_value_processed' => false,
                                            'attribute_scope' => 'parent',
                                        ),
                                ),
                        ),
                ),
        );
```

Comment: can you lease provide full code?